# how can I add video url to external database in android?

Tags: android, database, video, external

I'm using Hostinger’s free web hosting server. I made table there and want to adda url and some details on the table.

So here is my php file

```html
<?php
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $vehiclename = $_POST['vehiclename'];
 $vehicleUrl= $_POST[vehicleUrl];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $note = $_POST['note'];
 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 
 $sql ="SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY id ASC";
 
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 $id = 0;
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 }
 
 $path = "uploads/$id.mp4";
 
 $actualpath = "http://trafficviolation.esy.es/hosting/$path";
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (vehiclename,vehicleUrl,date,location,note) VALUES ('$vehiclename','$actualpath','$date','$location','$note')";
 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($vehicleUrl));
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";
 }
 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }


?>
```

here is my ActivityVedio.java class

```html
public class ActivityVideo extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public VideoView vid;
    EditText vehiclename;
    EditText note;
    EditText date1;
    EditText location;
    public Uri file;
    String a;
    public static final String UPLOAD_URL_VIdeo = "http://trafficviolation.esy.es/hosting/upload1Copy1.php";
    private String selectedPath;
    private String KEY_VIDEO = "vehicleUrl";
    private String KEY_NAME = "vehiclename";
    private String DATE = "date";
    private String LOCATION = "location";
    private String NOTE = "note";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        vid=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.imViewVideo);

        date1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        location= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
        vehiclename= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        note= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        file = Uri.parse(i.getExtras().get("vidFile").toString());
        selectedPath=i.getStringExtra("vidFile");
        String dateTime=i.getStringExtra("date");
        String a="abc";
        if(dateTime.equals(a)){
           
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
            File file = new File(selectedPath);
            Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
            String strDate = sdfDate.format(lastModDate);

            date1.setText(strDate);
        }
        else{
            date1.setText(dateTime);
        }
        location.setText(i.getStringExtra("location"));

// Show video on videoview
        vid.setVideoURI(file);
        MediaController mediaController = new
                MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vid);
        vid.setMediaController(mediaController);

        vid.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            }
        });

        vid.start();

        }


   
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save:
                uploadVideo(); // ***Error on logcat :  at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityVideo.java:158)***
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void uploadVideo() {
        String hname = vehiclename.getText().toString().trim();
        String hdate = date1.getText().toString().trim();
        String hlocation = location.getText().toString().trim();
        String hnote = note.getText().toString().trim();
        upload(hname,hdate,hlocation,hnote);// ***Error on logcat :at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.uploadVideo(ActivityVideo.java:172)***
    }

    private void upload(String hname, String hdate, String hlocation, String hnote) {
        class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog uploading;
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                uploading = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityVideo.this, "Uploading Video", "Please wait...", false, false);// ***Error on logcat at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo$1UploadVideo.onPreExecute(ActivityVideo.java:183)***
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                uploading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              
int bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
                FileInputStream  objFileIS = null;
                try
                {
                    objFileIS = new FileInputStream(selectedPath);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                
                try
                {
                    bytesAvailable = objFileIS.available();
                    Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1*1024*1024);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = objFileIS.read(buffer)) != -1;)
                    {
                        objByteArrayOS.write(buffer, 0, readNum);
                    }

                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            


                String videodata = Base64.encodeToString(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);


                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(KEY_VIDEO, videodata);
                data.put(KEY_NAME,params[0]);
                data.put(DATE,params[1]);
                data.put(LOCATION,params[2]);
                data.put(NOTE,params[3]);
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL_VIdeo,data);

                return result;
            }
        }
        UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
        uv.execute(hname,hdate,hlocation,hnote);// ***Error on logcat :   at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.upload(ActivityVideo.java:254)***
    }


}
```

So this worked me for some videos only. But for some videos this code did not work for me. So how can I fix this error?

Error report is like this

```
Activity com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42182f80 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42182f80 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:304)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
    at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo$1UploadVideo.onPreExecute(ActivityVideo.java:183)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.upload(ActivityVideo.java:254)
    at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.uploadVideo(ActivityVideo.java:172)
    at com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityVideo.java:158)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4278)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is at line `ActivityVideo.java:183`??

Comment: ActivityVideo.java:183 :                uploading = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityVideo.this, "Uploading Video", "Please wait...", false, false);

Comment: I added all error places on ActivityVideo.java class as comments.

Comment: Only 271KB size video file is uploaded using this cord snippet.More than that size could not be uploaded. So may be the error is with the size.So can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ProgressDialog` outside `AsyncTask`

```
private void upload(String hname, String hdate, String hlocation, String hnote) {
    final ProgressDialog uploading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    uploading.setTitle("Uploading Video");
    uploading.setMessage("Please wait...");
    uploading.setCancelable(true);
    class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            uploading.show();
            // rest of your code....
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            uploading.dismiss();
            // rest of your code here....
        }


    }
    //....
}
```

It may solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for late implement. But tthis did not work for me.I declared ProgressDialog outside AsyncTask. So I also want edit   in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)  ,uploadVideo()
to upload(vehiclename.getText().toString().trim(),date1.getText().toString().trim(),location.getText().toString().trim(),note.getText().toString().trim());  But this is not worked.After I click save button no actions happened

Comment: you have to click on options item to execute this method....If you want to work it on click of save button then call `upload` method on button click event.

Comment: Yes.i did that.But errors are coming. "Activity com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42ce0f78 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.t_buddhika.cam_17_2.ActivityVideo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42ce0f78 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here"